# Windows Vista/7 Pre-loading Mechanism?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

This question is related to this: [How to enable Java Quick Starter (JQS) on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/655510/how-to-enable-java-quick-starter-jqs-on-windows-7)

While searching for an answer, I came upon a [JQS help article](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/quickstarter.xml).

Quote:

> JQS is enabled by default in Windows XP and Windows 2000 operating systems and **JQS is not necessary on Windows Vista or Windows 7 as both offer their own pre-loading mechanisms**. A process called jqs.exe will run in the background in order to allow quick startup. jqs.exe will be loaded after a Windows restart. Instructions on how to disable the JQS and the jqs.exe process are below.

What is the pre-loading mechanism that is mentioned in this article? Can someone explain it and how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it refers to [superfetch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_I/O_technologies#SuperFetch), which is an improved version of the preloader XP had according to this [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.03.vistakernel.aspx) article. It automatically works out what you use the most, and caches it in spare ram for more speed.

Its probably not very useful if it isn't helping the OP of that other question already since you can't explicitly tell windows what program to cache.